# Mysql2 throwing lru0cache error when deploying on shared hosting

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, shared-hosting

```
backend/node_modules/mysql2/node_modules/lru-cache/dist/cjs/index.js:51
    heap;
        ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:152:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:605:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

When I am running index.js in my ssh terminal of hostinger Shared Hosting. I am creating mysql2 connection to my online db.
Working fine in local machine.

When using mysql package it is automatically closing connection both in local and on server.

This is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": myapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "basic-ftp": "^5.0.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "ftp": "^0.3.10",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lru-cache": "^10.1.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1"
  }
}
```

I want a solution to run it on server. Even tried deleting node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstalling

Comment: Your node.js version is likely too old. The line that triggers the error is a class property. Not sure exactly when those were added.

Comment: Yes, there was an older version installed on server which was causing error. Deleted that and installed new resolved error.